# Three.js drag to look around

Tags: javascript, three.js

For a project that I am doing, I want to do something like `THREE.OrbitControls`:

```
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

but not have the camera move.

I'm looking for some three.js plugin (like `OrbitControls`), or some code to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: You can drag with `THREE.OrbitControls` with the right click

Comment: @neeh That moves the whole camera. I want it to stay in one place but when I drag, it looks around

Comment: I don't really understand what you want, is it a third-person camera?

Comment: @neeh I want a first-person camera that doesn't move but rotates when I drag the mouse

Comment: Pls take a look at this exaple http://jsfiddle.net/Stemkoski/ddbTy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the camera at the center of your scene and rotate only, you can use `OrbitControls` and this pattern:

```
// camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( ... );
camera.position.set( 0, 0, 0.01 ); // OrbitControls target is the origin

// controls
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use this only if there is no animation loop
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.enablePan = false;
```

three.js r.84